# null pointer exception when trying to access RGB value of a pixel of a jpg image

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, rgb, pixel

I am writing a program that involves trying to access a specific pixel of a buffered image generated by another program. This however resulted in a null pointer exception that traced back to this line of code

```
int pixel=image.getRGB(coord.getX(),coord.getY());
```

in this specific instance, the coordinate is (32,281) and is well within the boundary of the image as shown below

```
System.out.print("this is the pixel: "+p+"\n");
System.out.print("image height: "+ imagedecoder.image.getHeight()+"\n");
System.out.print("image width: "+ imagedecoder.image.getWidth()+"\n");  
System.out.println("coordinate("+
    Integer.toString(coord.getX())+";"+Integer.toString(coord.getY())+")");
```

Output:

```
this is the pixel: -1
image height: 357
image width: 363
coordinate(32;281)
```

Another thing that i find it strange is that the pixel value is -1 comparing to other pixels that are right next to it for example (32,280) which is -197380

I am very confused as to what the null pointer exception is pointing to and why does it pop up at all

any help would be helpful

thank you

Comment: please include the full exception in your question

Comment: In one you use `image` in an other you use `imagedecoder.image`. Are you sure you are referring to the same image?  As you see, with incomplete example we cannot help much: we lack information.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. they are indeed referring to the same image the code came from two different classes within the same package. However after some tinkling with my code, the null point exception just kind of disappeared. It might have something to do with removing the static key word in front of the buffered image? Anyway I have been unable to reproduce the error message so just going to consider the problem solved. thank you everyone who takes time and looked at my problem